# Calloc differences between MS Windows and Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, calloc

I wrote some code to calloc memory until there is no more available.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int *p;
    int count = 0;
    while(1) 
    {
        int inc=1024*1024*sizeof(char);
        p=(int*) calloc(1,inc);
        count++;
        if(!p)
        {
            cout << "managed to allocate " << (count * 1024 * 1024) / 1000000000.0 << " gb\n";
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Executing the above code on Windows in Visual Studio I get the following:

```
managed to allocate 1.9881 gb
Press any key to continue . . .
```

However, when I bring it to my Linux system and compile and run with the following:

```
g++ mem.cpp
./a.out
```

The process gets killed by the os after a bit.

It seems like calloc will not return null even if the memory being allocated doesn't exist?

If that is the case, then how can I modify my existing code to achieve the same effect on Linux as on Windows?

Comment: why are you using `calloc()` with c++ at all, instead of using the [Dynamic memory management](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) features of the standard library?

Comment: In C++ I would recommend using `new` instead of `calloc` then trying to handle the [`bad_alloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc)

Comment: @CoryKramer No, not `new` please. Refer to what I've been linking please.

Comment: Search for "overcommit" on Linux, it might be the reason your process is killed.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Agreed, though to be honest, I'm still not even sure what the OP is hoping to find from their code. Available memory? There are certainly better ways to do so than just allocating until it dies.

Comment: If your OS decided to kill your program, it's incorrect to assume that `calloc` failed.

Comment: @CoryKramer I am trying to find the maximum amount of memory a process can allocate on my system. I do not want the process to die. That is the unintended side effect of running on linux that I am trying to resolve.

Comment: I'd call it a reasonable assumption that `calloc()` had something to do with the unexpected behaviour, @Drew, as nothing else there is likely to fail. If you have any better approaches to solving this issue I'd be interested.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt my understanding is similar to [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153585).  If an OOM killer terminates your process, it's not evidence that your process was the last to attempt a memory allocation.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because Linux "overcommits" memory. Processes on Linux can allocate more memory than is physically available. Physical memory is allocated only when the memory is actually used.

When Linux runs out of available physical memory it starts killing processes until memory is freed up.

You can disable this behavior system wide with:

```
sudo sysctl -w vm.overcommit_memory=2
```

It will make sure all allocated physical memory is actually there. It might not be a good idea. Many programs rely on this behavior and allocate a lot of never used memory.

It is also not a good idea to consume all available memory. Your program might not be the one which fails to allocate memory or the one which is killed by OOM killer. You are affecting all processes in your system.

Comment: Tried this. Now **every** command I enter says

    "-bash: fork: Cannot allocate memory"

Comment: You have been warned. Your system probably already allocated more memory than is physically available and will not allocate any more.

Comment: Yup, Linux memory handling is notoriously bad. It's a bit of a chicken and egg problem for them: Their non-standard behavior is in reaction to badly implemented programs (which ask for more memory than they need), and now programs take this bad solution into account. So it's fixed by the desire for backwards compatibility. This is also one of the reasons Linux needs hacks like LXC : the kernel itself fails to properly shield the processes from different users. You can OOM-kill somebody elses process.